# Oracle database insert issue

Tags: oracle

I am passing an insert statement to my db as follows

```
INSERT INTO W_GL_BALANCE_FS(BUSN_AREA_ORG_ID,GL_ACCOUNT_ID,BALANCE_DATE,DB_CR_IND,BALANCE_ACCT_AMT,BALANCE_LOC_AMT,ACTIVITY_ACCT_AMT,ACTIVITY_LOC_AMT,ACCT_CURR_CODE,LOC_CURR_CODE,INTEGRATION_ID,DATASOURCE_NUM_ID,TENANT_ID,X_CUSTOM,ADJUSTMENT_FLAG,BALANCE_TYPE_FLAG,TRANSLATED_FLAG,SUMMARY_ACCOUNT_FLAG,LAST_UPDATE_DATE,AUX1_CHANGED_ON_DT,AUX2_CHANGED_ON_DT,LEDGER_ID) 
VALUES ( "-1"
,"1004",
"07/31/2013 00:00:00.000000000",
"DEBIT",
"0.00000000000000",
"1.68195141463052e+18",
"0.00000000000000",
"0.00000000000000",
"NULL",
"AED",
"GL~1002~1004~JUL-13~DEBIT~A~N~AED~NULL~",
"90.00000000000000",
"DEFAULT",
"(NULL)",
"N",
"A",
"N",
"N",
"08/12/2013 11:14:06.000000000",
"10/15/2013 00:00:00.000000000",
"07/05/2012 15:04:22.000000000",
"1002")
```

but it showing an error

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
INSERT INTO W_GL_BALANCE_FS(BUSN_AREA_ORG_ID,GL_ACCOUNT_ID,BALANCE_DATE,DB_CR_IND,BALANCE_ACCT_AMT,BALANCE_LOC_AMT,ACTIVITY_ACCT_AMT,ACTIVITY_LOC_AMT,ACCT_CURR_CODE,LOC_CURR_CODE,INTEGRATION_ID,DATASOURCE_NUM_ID,TENANT_ID,X_CUSTOM,ADJUSTMENT_FLAG,BALANCE_TYPE_FLAG,TRANSLATED_FLAG,SUMMARY_ACCOUNT_FLAG,LAST_UPDATE_DATE,AUX1_CHANGED_ON_DT,AUX2_CHANGED_ON_DT,LEDGER_ID) 
VALUES ( "-1"
,"1004",
"07/31/2013 00:00:00.000000000",
"DEBIT",
"0.00000000000000",
"1.68195141463052e+18",
"0.00000000000000",
"0.00000000000000",
"NULL",
"AED",
"GL~1002~1004~JUL-13~DEBIT",
"90.00000000000000",
"DEFAULT",
"(NULL)",
"N",
"A",
"N",
"N",
"08/12/2013 11:14:06.000000000",
"10/15/2013 00:00:00.000000000",
"07/05/2012 15:04:22.000000000",
"1002") 
Error at Command Line:23 Column:1
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
00984. 00000 -  "column not allowed here"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error starting at line 1 in command:
INSERT INTO W_GL_BALANCE_FS(BUSN_AREA_ORG_ID,GL_ACCOUNT_ID,BALANCE_DATE,DB_CR_IND,BALANCE_ACCT_AMT,BALANCE_LOC_AMT,ACTIVITY_ACCT_AMT,ACTIVITY_LOC_AMT,ACCT_CURR_CODE,LOC_CURR_CODE,INTEGRATION_ID,DATASOURCE_NUM_ID,TENANT_ID,X_CUSTOM,ADJUSTMENT_FLAG,BALANCE_TYPE_FLAG,TRANSLATED_FLAG,SUMMARY_ACCOUNT_FLAG,LAST_UPDATE_DATE,AUX1_CHANGED_ON_DT,AUX2_CHANGED_ON_DT,LEDGER_ID) 
VALUES ( "-1"
,"1004",
"07/31/2013 00:00:00.000000000",
"DEBIT",
"0.00000000000000",
"1.68195141463052e+18",
"0.00000000000000",
"0.00000000000000",
"NULL",
"AED",
"GL~1002~1004~JUL-13~DEBIT~A~N~AED~NULL~",
"90.00000000000000",
"DEFAULT",
"(NULL)",
"N",
"A",
"N",
"N",
"08/12/2013 11:14:06.000000000",
"10/15/2013 00:00:00.000000000",
"07/05/2012 15:04:22.000000000",
"1002") 
Error at Command Line:12 Column:1
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00972: identifier is too long
00972. 00000 -  "identifier is too long"
*Cause:    An identifier with more than 30 characters was specified.
*Action:   Specify at most 30 characters.
```

The desc of my table is as follows

```
desc w_gl_balance_fs
Name                 Null     Type               
-------------------- -------- ------------------ 
COMPANY_ORG_ID                VARCHAR2(80 CHAR)  
BUSN_AREA_ORG_ID     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(80 CHAR)  
GL_ACCOUNT_ID        NOT NULL VARCHAR2(240 CHAR) 
BALANCE_DATE                  DATE               
DB_CR_IND                     VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)  
BALANCE_ACCT_AMT              NUMBER(28,10)      
BALANCE_LOC_AMT               NUMBER(28,10)      
ACTIVITY_ACCT_AMT             NUMBER(28,10)      
ACTIVITY_LOC_AMT              NUMBER(28,10)      
ACCT_CURR_CODE       NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30 CHAR)  
LOC_CURR_CODE        NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30 CHAR)  
INTEGRATION_ID       NOT NULL VARCHAR2(150 CHAR) 
DATASOURCE_NUM_ID    NOT NULL NUMBER(10)         
ETL_PROC_WID                  NUMBER(10)         
TENANT_ID                     VARCHAR2(80 CHAR)  
X_CUSTOM                      VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)  
ADJUSTMENT_FLAG               VARCHAR2(1 CHAR)   
BALANCE_TYPE_FLAG             VARCHAR2(1 CHAR)   
TRANSLATED_FLAG               VARCHAR2(1 CHAR)   
SUMMARY_ACCOUNT_FLAG          VARCHAR2(1 CHAR)   
CREATED_ON_DT                 DATE               
LAST_UPDATE_DATE              DATE               
AUX1_CHANGED_ON_DT            DATE               
AUX2_CHANGED_ON_DT            DATE               
AUX3_CHANGED_ON_DT            DATE               
AUX4_CHANGED_ON_DT            DATE               
LEDGER_ID                     VARCHAR2(80 CHAR)  
PROFIT_CENTER_ID              VARCHAR2(80 CHAR)  
BALANCE_ID                    VARCHAR2(240 CHAR)
```

Comment: You shouldn't enclose your values in double quotes. If something is a string, enclose it in apostrophes like `'string'`. Otherwise, drop the quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Use single-quotes instead of double-quotes.. You should also probably use `to_date` for inserting date values:

```
INSERT INTO W_GL_BALANCE_FS   (BUSN_AREA_ORG_ID,GL_ACCOUNT_ID,BALANCE_DATE,DB_CR_IND,BALANCE_ACCT_AMT,BALANCE_LOC_AMT,ACTIVITY_ACCT_AMT,ACTIVITY_LOC_AMT,ACCT_CURR_CODE,LOC_CURR_CODE,INTEGRATION_ID,DATASOURCE_NUM_ID,TENANT_ID,X_CUSTOM,ADJUSTMENT_FLAG,BALANCE_TYPE_FLAG,TRANSLATED_FLAG,SUMMARY_ACCOUNT_FLAG,LAST_UPDATE_DATE,AUX1_CHANGED_ON_DT,AUX2_CHANGED_ON_DT,LEDGER_ID) 
VALUES ( '-1'
,'1004',
to_date('07/31/2013','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
'DEBIT',
'0.00000000000000',
'1.68195141463052e+18',
'0.00000000000000',
'0.00000000000000',
'NULL',
'AED',
'GL~1002~1004~JUL-13~DEBIT~A~N~AED~NULL~',
'90.00000000000000',
'DEFAULT',
'(NULL)',
'N',
'A',
'N',
'N',
to_date('08/12/2013 11:14:06','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
to_date('10/15/2013','dd/mm/yyyy'),
to_date('07/05/2012 15:04:22','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
'1002')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose the string values in `single quote('')`

Example:

```
INSERT INTO mytable(column1) values('col1 value');
```